# How to encrypt and hide a GNU/Linux operating system and create a decoy system?

Tags: encryption, linux, operating-systems, steganography, qubes-os

My goal is to be protected against key disclosure laws and possible extortion. I know **dm-crypt** can be used to perform full disk encryption for GNU/Linux distros. However, it is not enough. I want to be able to hide an operating system in an encrypted hidden partition and create a decoy system for plausible deniability (à la **Veracrypt** and **TrueCrypt**). Furthermore, I cannot use **Veracrypt** or **TrueCrypt** as they do not support **Operating System Encryption** for anything other than Windows. Is there such a tool for GNU/Linux distros. In reality, I mainly use QubesOS, therefore I'm asking this question for both GNU/Linux distros and QubesOS.

Comment: I recall reading about some ways to do this with dm-crypt manually, but it would require the code to do it be in a bootloader that's either unencrypted, or not encrypted using plausible deniability. Alternatively, it would require you memorize the commands and offsets. But there's no simple, easy way to do this.